# OAuth for node-red flows

Tags: node-red

I want to implement OAuth for the flow in the node-red for which there is a node OAuth2 added following the link https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-oauth2
I want to know the actual steps to be followed to implement OAuth in node-red

Comment: You are going to need to add a lot more details about what you are trying to do here. That node is for authenticating against a 3rd party service, not requiring oAuth authentication of clients accessing your flow.

Comment: I may have misunderstood that node and yes my requirement is OAuth authentication of clients accessing the flow.

Comment: There is no easy way to add oAuth authentication to an API implemented using http-in/http-response nodes without embedding NR in to a custom app and inserting custom middleware

Comment: So to be more clear is this what you are saying
There should be an application that will be acting as a middleware where on authentication it will redirected to node red flow

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a self-hosted FusionAuth instance from Node-red via their API. This gives me OAUTH2 using both apple and google, as well as a working user database and more.

https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/